# UIBarButtonItem Title Alignment left and right aligned

Tags: objective-c

When I changed the language to Arabic, I want to change the UIBarButtonItem title to Left or Right Aligned.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 50)];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

```
UIBarButtonItem *btdone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(Done)];
UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,btdone, nil]];
```

Space BarButton provide u space